# Wordpress CSS - two layout questions

Tags: css, layout, scroll, background-color

1. Why do I have sideways scroll   :-(  http://www.startingpointstables.com/riding-lessons/

And

1. Why are the thumbnails in on the home page going UNDER their container divs in FF?  http://www.startingpointstables.com

And finally

1. When you resize the browser down to the 700 px range and the sidebar drops down below the content... where is the 'white box' coming from under the widgets div?  http://www.startingpointstables.com/riding-lessons/

:-(  Why is working on your own website 1000 times more frustrating than working on someone elses?  I had things going good and I don't know what the heck I did but it all went pear shaped.  :-\

Answer (score 0):

Try to give some minimum height to the div's you have created, like this--

```
div{min-height:500px;}
```